# tabitem hide show in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Tabitem hide show in silverlight

Comment: You could use google for this.

Answer (score 4):

```
myTabItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // hidden
myTabItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // shown
```